# Is there a valid way to include my <span> element within the following JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, validation, xhtml-1.0-strict

I have this simple little JavaScript snippet to try and protect my email address a little:

```
<p>Email:<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
    mixupE='mywebsite.com'
    mixupE=('myname' + '<span>@</span>' + mixupE)
    document.write(mixupE)
</script>
</p>
```

The problem is that it is the only section of code that doesn't validate a xhtml strict. It's to do with the span @ /span part. I have just include the span so that I can style the @ symbol different to the rest of the email address.

Anyone got any better ways of doing this?

Ideally I'd like to get everything to validate :o)

I've solved it by just doing this at the moment:

```
<p>Email:<br />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            mixupA='name'
            mixupA=('my' + mixupA)
            document.write(mixupA)
        </script><span>@</span><script type="text/javascript">
            mixupB='site.com'
            mixupB=('myweb' + mixupB)
            document.write(mixupB)
        </script>
</p>
```

Probably not the best way of doing things, but it seems to work and my pages now validate as xhtml strict :o)

Comment: `document.write` isn't advisable , instead set the innerHTML

Comment: i can suggest a better way of protecting your email address: invert your email address(either by js or hardcoding it or by using your backend's string invert) then re-invert it using the css: rtl property so real people can actually read it right, while spam bots read it inverted.

Comment: How about if I was to do what I'm doing now with js, but write the letters backwards to have it show it inverted and then re-invert it with css later? Sound good?

Comment: Backwards text screws up Copy + Paste. It shows up backwards when you paste it, but looks okay on the webpage.

Comment: Thanks blender! You're right! I think I'll change my text to the right way round again, as copy + paste is pretty important in my view :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an indirect way of representing `<`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var lt = String.fromCharCode(60);
  mixupE='mywebsite.com'
  mixupE=('myname' + lt + 'span>@' + lt + '/span>' + mixupE)
  document.write(mixupE)
</script>
```

Comment: This sounded good, but doesn't seem to work for some reason? It's not showing the email address when the xhtml page is loaded. Hmmm...?

Comment: Sorry, `String.fromCharCode(60)`

Comment: ahh... ok this does work now, thanks :o) I might try this rather than the rather long winded fix that I just added as an update to my original question.

Comment: I just up voted it for you. I thought it was a good answer! :o)

Comment: Would it be a good idea to include the CDATA blocks along with this code?

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap the element in a CDATA block as described in the section of the specification on the differences between HTML and XHTML, specifically the [script and style elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8) section.

However, you are almost certainly serving your XHTML up with a text/html Content-Type, so you need to jump through the hoops of making it HTML-like enough to continue to work cross-browser. In this case, [by commenting out the CDATA markers](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_4).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    mixupE='mywebsite.com'
    mixupE=('myname' + '<span>@</span>' + mixupE)
    document.write(mixupE)
    //]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Isn't the ending script tag duplicated?

Comment: I don't fully understand this yet, but I'm going to look into it. I guessed that that it was basically some kind of nesting error relating to the fact that you're not really supposed to have a span element within a script element. Thanks for your help everyone :o)

Answer (score 0):

Here's where I'm at with things guys. I have the following two possibilities that both seem to work and which both validate as strict xhtml.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   <!--
   var lt = String.fromCharCode(60);
   mixupE='mywebsite.com'
   mixupE=('myname' + lt + 'span>@' + lt + '/span>' + mixupE)
   document.write(mixupE)
   //-->
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   //<![CDATA[
   mixupE='mywebsite.com'
   mixupE=('myname' + '<span>@</span>' + mixupE)
   document.write(mixupE)
   //]]>
</script>
```

Any reasons why I should go for one of these over the other?

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of CDATA and escapes, as so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
mixupE="mywebsite.com";
mixupE=("myname" + "<span>@<\/span>" + mixupE);
document.write(mixupE);
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is just to split up the strings so it doesn't think it's an entity. This is perfectly valid, and almost identical to you original:

```
<p>Email:<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
    mixupE='mywebsite.com'
    mixupE=('myname<' + 'span>@<' + '/span>' + mixupE)
    document.write(mixupE)
</script>
</p>
```

There's no need to obfuscate the angle bracket.

But don't forget your `var` and `;`. Simplified it's:

```
<p>Email:<br />
<script type="text/javascript">
    var mixupE='mywebsite.com';
    document.write('myname<' + 'span>@<' + '/span>' + mixupE);
</script>
</p>
```